# Persistent problem trying to use AJAX to edit modal data in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

I've been looking at various ways of the process of obtaining an ID and its contents within a modal using AJAX and Laravel. All I'm trying to accomplish is to allow a user to edit a reply by clicking on modal. I am aware I need to fetch the ID of a selected reply and pass that ID to the controller and target that reply. I have a one-to-many relationship between 'Ticket aka a Post' & 'Reply'. What does work is submitting the data to the database using AJAX, however, when clicking 'Confirm' to edit the reply, the content seems to change all of the replies and not just the one that was selected. I've tried adding a data=id field and using my reply->id, as well as giving my actual modal a reply->id and data-target reply-id; this seems to work but again doesn't uniquely identify which reply I want to update.

**TicketController**

```php
public function editReply(Ticket $ticket)
{
    $message = request()->input('message');
    $ticket->reply()->update(['message' => $message]);

    return response()->json($message);
}
```

**Ticket Blade**

```php
@foreach($slug->reply as $r)
    <div class="card-footer reply-footer bg-transparent" style="height: 2.5rem">
        @if(Auth::user()->id == $r->user->id )
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark" id="open-modal"
                    data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{$r->id}}"
                    data-target="#edit-modal">Edit
            </button>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach

<!-- edit reply modal !-->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="edit-modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="tit">Edit</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="edit-reply">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" name="replyID">
                        <textarea class="form-control testing" id="edit-box" rows="12"
                                  name="edit-message"
                                  required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark"
                            id="edit-button" data-dismiss="modal"
                            style="font-weight: bold;">Confirm
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#edit-button').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('ticket.edit-reply', $slug->slug) }}",
                type: 'PATCH',
                data: {
                    message: jQuery('#edit-box').val()
                },
                success: function (result, exception) {
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status + ' - ' + exception);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Ticket Model**

```php
class Ticket extends Model
{
    public function reply()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

**Reply Model**

```php
class Reply extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'message', 'user_id', 'ticket_id', 'edit-message'
    ];

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

So at the moment it updates all replies instead of just one, so am I meant to somehow use a GET (which I researched before) but then thought how would I use a GET with AJAX to fetch the ID in association with the controller and then a PATCH to submit the data using another method to submit the data? Unless I just make two separate  doing each task independently?

Some guidance pointing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated as I've been trying to suss this out for about a week now.

Comment: You need to enumerate your models. Model Ticket? Model Reply? Model Post?

Comment: What model is the relation `$ticket->reply()` referring to?

Comment: So as a 'ticket' has multiple replies, I'm updating the message (of Reply model) through Ticket model. And the only models are Ticket and Reply for this functionality

Comment: Then you need to pass a value to replyID in the form along with the edit-message. And not doing a `$ticket->reply()->update()` cause it's updating whole replies. I gonna try an answer

Comment: Ohh right okay makes sense. So do I need to uniquely identify each modal within the loop or use data-id at all in order to fetch this particular MESSAGE id to update?

Comment: Yes exactly. You would load the `$reply` directly in method parameter as `editReply(Reply $reply)` instead of `editReply(Ticket $ticket)`, or just search it with `$reply = Reply::find(request()->replyID);` and call `$reply->update()`.

Comment: Okay so it's not necessary for me to access it through the relationship then? I guess I can go straight for the reply as you've just shown. So when I route it just pass the 'id' and pass it through to the modal on click?

Comment: Yes you can change it to reply route instead for easier way to go. Or you can still go with the Ticket route if you want to verify that the replyID is for that ticket, but it's not necessary to verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All records got updated because `$ticket->reply()` return all replies, and `->update()` is called for all of them.

YOu must instead look for that single edited Reply. In blade you must specify in the form the replyID to be edited. The same way you put message in

```
<textarea class="form-control testing" id="edit-box" rows="12" name="edit-message" required></textarea>
```

you will put replyID in

```
<input type="hidden" name="replyID">
```

And in Controller you can have :

```
public function editReply()
{
    $reply = Reply::find(request()->input('replyID'));
    $message = request()->input('edit-message');
    $reply->update(['message' => $message]);
    return response()->json($message);
}
```

Or if your URI is already containing the $replyID a parameter then :

```
public function editReply(Reply $reply)
{
    $message = request()->input('edit-message');
    $reply->update(['message' => $message]);
    return response()->json($message);
}
```

And 2 things you should do :

1 - Change Many side relation to plural for more standard :

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
 public function replies(){
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

 public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

2 - Verify ownership in controller like you did in Blade view cause anyone can change the `replyID` value in Browser and edit another one's reply.

Comment: Fixed it now thank you very much for your support I very much appreciate it. I turned out I had to use the message key of my 'data' object in AJAX, in my ontroller instead of input('edit-message'), and also add in my ID into the data object too and use that key in the controller as well.

Comment: Ok Good to know you resolved it. I put `'edit-message'` in controller because you put `'edit-message'` in your blade view. I just forgot to mention it specifically.